# Application error while deploying a MERN stack app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to deploy a MERN Stack application on Heroku. After performing any action related to backend, like Sign Up, Login and uploading a product, I am getting the error 503 every time.

Eg: Error 503 after trying to Sign Up:

[image]

root file of backend (index.js):

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
var cors=require('cors');

const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT||5000;
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require("path");
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

const uri=process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri,{
  useNewUrlParser:true,
  useUnifiedTopology:true
})

const connection=mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open",()=>
console.log('MongoDB connection established'));


app.use(bodyParser.json())
//Available Routes
app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/auth'));

app.use('/articles',require('./routes/articles'));

// Step 1:
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build")));
// Step 2:
app.get("*", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html"));
});



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Biased Notebook listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

This is the package.json file:

```
  "name": "inotebook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "inotebook backend",
  "main": "index.js",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "prithesh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "formidable": "^2.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.11",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Procfile:
`web:npm start`

You can find the entire repository [here](https://github.com/JUNKIEJAM/e-auction-depp). Client folder is inside the backend folder for the purpose of deploying.

Comment: It could have to do with using bodyParser, which is deprecated.  It's now bundled with express, so you can get rid of any reference to bodyParser, which is likely the "unavailable service" the error is describing.

Comment: Unless any of your routes specifically responds with a 503, this error is most likely due to a communications issue between the public facing reverse-proxy and your Express service. That being said, do any of your routes use `res.status(503)` or similar?

Comment: What do your server logs say? Perhaps something is crashing the entire app, hence the _"Service Unavailable"_ message

Comment: @Phil None of my routes is set to respond with res.status(503).